# Flutter: Firebase_Analytics - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I have updated my flutter to the latest version 1.20 and also performed the steps for the Xcode 11.4 Support. After performing these steps getting below architecture-related errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_analytics(FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalyticsConfiguration)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

- Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Also, I am using the latest version of the [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics): **^6.0.0** in my pubspec.yaml.

- **iOS Podfile:**

```
     platform :ios, '9.0'
    
    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
      
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
      
      pod 'Firebase/Core'
      pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.8.0'
      pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults', '~> 3.0.0'
      pod 'RSMasterTableView', :git => 'https://github.com/DhavalRKansara/RSMasterTableView.git'
      pod 'CryptoSwift'
      pod 'SwiftR' , :git => 'https://github.com/DhavalRKansara/SwiftR.git'
      pod 'SKPhotoBrowser'
      pod 'RSSelectionMenu'
      pod 'JJFloatingActionButton'
      pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
      pod 'MarqueeLabel'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
      
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
```

**Note:** I have also raised and [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3434) under the flutterfire on GitHub for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode project is targeting x86_64 which is for MacOS.
You will need to either rollback to arm64, or you can run this command to recreate the iOS project to its default (make sure to backup the flutter project first): **(Run this command only if you do not have any changes done specifically on the xcode project, such as assets or icons)**

```
flutter create  -i swift .
```

or for objective-c:

```
flutter create  -i objc .
```

If you do need to develop for MacOS you will need to create a seperate macos folder on the flutter project (https://flutter.dev/desktop).

Run these commands:

```
flutter channel dev
```

To switch to the alpha channel (MacOS is still not stable for flutter)

```
flutter upgrade

flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
```

Then reboot the IDE, and run this command if you do not see the macos folder in your flutter project:

```
flutter create .
```

This will add/repair any missing files (**make sure to back your project first**).
Then simply run this command to deploy for macos:

```
flutter run -d macos --release
```